# Which command in my code is preventing a custom theme and legend labels from working?

Tags: ggplot2, themes, legend

So i am trying to make graph mapping coral cover degradation. From the attached graph you can see i am almost there, i am just trying to add custom labels to my legend and a custom theme to change up the colours.
This code produces a graph but seems to ignore my custom theme and labels.

Thanks for the help!

```
ggplot(CCR, aes(x=as.factor(Year),y=mean, group=Site,color=Site))+
geom_point(size=3)+
labs(y="Hard Coral Cover %",x="Year")+
geom_line(size=2)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd,ymax=mean+sd),width=.1,colour="black")+
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,110), expand=c(0,0))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold"),legend.title=element_text(face="bold"))+ 
scale_fill_npg(labels=c("Bouy 3","Sampela 1","Pak Kasims","Kaledupa 1","Kaledupa Double Spur","Ridge 1"),guide=guide_legend(title="Site"))+
theme_base()
```

[Graph produced from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afS0i.png)

Comment: You added `theme_base` at the end, which overrides your previous theme settings. Move your custom `theme(...)` to the end, and it will act to modify `theme_base` instead of the other way around.

Comment: Also your colours/labels are wrong because you used `scale_fill` but mapped your variable `color = Site`. Change to `scale_color_npg(...)` and that will be fixed.